# "this" variable not working when assigning JSONP array to AngularJS controller

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, jsonp

I have a REST service that I call in my angular controller via JSONP. I want to save the returned array to a variable.

Here is what I am doing:

```
this.testTheRest = function()
{
    $http.jsonp('myRESTService', {
            params: {
                callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK',
                format: 'json'
            }
        })
            .success(function (data) {
                this.testlist = data.NoParamsResult;
                console.log(this.testlist);
            })
            .error(function (data) {
                alert(data);
            });

        console.log(this.testlist);
}
```

I have defined testlist as a variable in the controller beforehand:

```
this.testlist = [];
```

Note the two console output calls. The problem is, that the first one shows the correct array:

```
Array [ Object, Object ]
```

But the second one shows an empty array (probably the one from initialization):

```
Array [  ]
```

What do I have to do to keep the returned objects in the array?

Thanks in advance,
Frank

Comment: IMHO Your bottom console.log should NOT be the same as the one inside "success" method. Your success method is called "back" when the server responds with the data, which occurs later. The bottom console.log statement is not really usefull, since the response has not ocured - so there should be no changes.

Comment: Then the answer is not correct...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a scoping issue.  Try assigning your outer `this` to another variable (e.g. `that`), then using that variable instead of `this`.

```
var that = this

that.testTheRest = function() {
    $http.jsonp('myRESTService', {
        params: {
            callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK',
            format: 'json'
        }
    })
    .success(function (data) {
        that.testlist = data.NoParamsResult;
        console.log(that.testlist);
    })
    .error(function (data) {
        alert(data);
    });
}
```